# With PHP MYSQL Prepared Statements and IFNULL() to return all records if value = ""

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, ifnull

I am trying to build a MySQL query using Prepared Statements that will ignore a criteria if it has been set to NULL. For example, in the below, if `$a = ""` and `$b = "10"`, I want the query to return all records where column b contains the value 10 and ignore the a criteria, because currently, the query would return all records that have a 'column a' value of "" and a 'column b' value of "10".

```
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT x, y FROM users WHERE a = IFNULL(?, %%) AND b = IFNULL(?, %%) AND ...")) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('ss...', $a, $b, ...); // Bind variables to parameter.
    $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();
    }
```

What should I replace '%%' with to return everything as if the criteria had not been set?

EDIT: Found an answer here that doesn't use prepared statements, but instead an array of allowed strings for security to stop SQL injections.

[Multiple Dropdowns Dynamic Query AJAX PHP MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561878/multiple-dropdowns-dynamic-query-ajax-php-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

You mean

```
WHERE ((a IS NULL) AND (b = 10))
```

?

Comment: yes, but also the other way round if applicable so that it is dynamic: WHERE ((b IS NULL) AND (a = 10))